# How to change user affilations to group in Linux

Tags: linux

I have several users say: A,B,C,D, etc. and 2 group: master, slave.
Each user belongs to only one of these groups (exclusively).
How can I programmatically change this belonging?

For example: user A belongs to group "master"
How to remove it from group "master" and add it to group "slave"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page of `usermod`:

```
-G, --groups group,...
With this option a list of supplementary groups can be specified, which the user should become a member of. Each group is separated from the next one only by a comma, without whitespace. The user is removed from all other groups not specified.


-R, --remove-from-group group,...
With this option a list of groups can be specified, from which the user should be removed. Each group is separated from the next one only by a comma, without whitespace.
```

If for some reason this isn't pre-installed on your system it is a command from the `pwdutils` package.